# Jump to specific location on the page based on elements class

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML elements and both of them are hidden at the start:

```
    <div class="alert alert-danger divMessage" id="lblErrorMobile" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="alert alert-success divMessage" id="lblSuccessMobile" style="display:none;"></div>
```

I know I can navigate to one or the another like this:

```
window.location.href = '#lblErrorMobile';
window.location.href = '#lblSuccessMobile';
```

Is it possible to navigate on each of these by class - let's say, a class `divMessage`?

My problem is that those labels are not shown by default. They are showing separately if there is error or success. And if I try to navigate on a label which is hidden, navigation does not happen. That is why navigating by class would be so handy - one or the other will be always visible.

Comment: Location hash based navigation works only for IDs. If you need custom behaviour, you will have to write JavaScript for it.

Comment: Put both of them in a div and jump to that div by id instead?

Comment: Good one @Aaron... I don't know why I haven't thought about it immediately.

Comment: @Aaron - please post this as answer. I know it's a simple one, but it solved my problem.

Comment: @FrenkyB done, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should use a container for both `div` that you will jump to instead of having to know which `div` you should jump to. For instance :

```
<div id="messages">
    <div class="alert alert-danger divMessage" id="lblErrorMobile" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="alert alert-success divMessage" id="lblSuccessMobile" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

Then jump to `#messages`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anchor tags to navigate around your site, without using Javascript.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejrEzL

```
<h2 id="top">top</h2>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<h2 id="middle">middle</h2>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<h2 id="end">end</h2>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div style="position: fixed; right: 10px; top: 10px;">
  <a href="#top">go to top</a>
  <a href="#middle">go to middle</a>
  <a href="#end">go to end</a>
</div>
```

Or using javascript you can using the following method:

```
var el = document.getElementById("my-element");
el.scrollIntoView();
```